# Bricked my Grundig MPixx 2001 by formatting it. Firmware updater doesn't work

Tags: virtualbox, firmware, mp3-player

**NOTE:** Please don't remove me. I can't find a proper Stack Exchange site for this question. Please just move it where it needs to be because I can't find a hardware based site.

I have a Grundig MPixx 2001 MP3 player. I wanted to clean up all my data from it by formatting it. When I did, the MP3 player couldn't recognize my files that I put onto it. Then, I formatted it again with a FAT file system and some default settings that Windows said are default. From there on, the MP3 player blinks every few seconds and is stuck in a boot loop.

I've downloaded a firmware updater from here: [Grundig Downloads](http://www.grundig.de/en/service/downloads/software/mpixx/)

But the firmware updater says that the operating system isn't supported. I tried going to VirtualBox, but then VirtualBox USB driver couldn't be found on Windows Update.

Now the acts like an unformatted device on my PC. When I plug it in, it shows me a logo for file transfering and some text like usual when transfering files.

What should I do now to bring it back into a functional state?

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed this myself. I had to format the device again, but this time without the full format option.

I started it up and it worked well. Luckily, the firmware wasn't overwritten. I made a voice recording and listened to it. Then, I put some music on it and it worked also.

The solution was to format it with quick format after the long formatting.